# Linux Maven config - setting JAVA_HOME breaks Maven

Tags: java, linux, maven, java-home

I am attempting to setup a Maven-Tomcat build on Linux. Stepping through the configuration processes, I have encountered a problem.

As title says, setting the `JAVA_HOME` in `.bashrc` will break my Maven configurations.

Without `JAVA_HOME` set, Maven gives the following output for `mvn -version`:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_91, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_IE, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.19.0-32-generic", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

However, once I set `JAVA_HOME` as any combination of the following:

```
#export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/
#export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
#export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

I am seeing the following output from `mvn -version`:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm//bin/java
```

It looks like there is an overlap in the path being set, somehow, somewhere.

Further to that affect - if I don't configure my `JAVA_HOME` in `.bashrc`, `echo %JAVA_HOME` returns empty. `which java`, however returns `/usr/bin/java`.

I've also gone the way of configuring `/etc/environment` as opposed to `.bashrc` but this returned the same results.

Any help on this is most appreciated, as I've been trying to fix for 2 days and feel like I am chasing my tail!

Comment: Did you try echo $JAVA_HOME instead of %JAVA_HOME?

Comment: sorry that is a type will correct

Comment: what does `ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java` show you?

Comment: Apache-tomcat and maven are included in Debian/Ubuntu, CentOS, Fedora ... and can be installed with the usual package install tools.

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5730 Jun 26 16:48 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java @krzyk

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

In your `.bashrc` file, after the above commands `which java` should show you the one from java-8-oracle directory, and executing `java -version` should print version information for it.

When you verify the above you can run `mvn` command.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a home subdirectory inside /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle.
Are the variables JRE_HOME or JDK_HOME set?

On my system
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home

which java
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

This is on Mac OS

Which LINUX are you using

I took a look at Ubuntu
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

which java
/usr/bin/java